# MathJax no longer loads a default configuration file

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

I have been getting this error message on Maths and Physics network

> MathJax no longer loads a default configuration file; you must specify such files explicitly. This page seems to use the older default config/MathJax.js file, and so needs to be updated. This is explained further at
>
> http://www.mathjax.org/help/configuration

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/what-is-this-error-and-how-can-it-be-rectified

Comment: I've seen this a few time in the last two months or so. No ability to reproduce it on demand, and it's been a while so perhaps it is finally gone.

Comment: I've never seen this message on Electrical Engineering, where it's also enabled.

Comment: I agree it does not seem reproducible, I have visited both networks again a few times but haven't seen the error again.

Comment: @balpha: I saw this problem recently on Electronics SE when viewing it on HTC Desire S Android device.