# Mathjax configuration error seems to be reproduceable on mobile version of SE sites

Tags: support, status-norepro, android, mathjax

[This problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113888/mathjax-no-longer-loads-a-default-configuration-file) with a popup saying MathJax is inconfigured seems to never be backed with a reliable repro. Looks like I have one.

The problem is reproed in default browser availavle on Android 2.3.5 (device is HTC Desire S if that matters) when opening [this question on Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17450/dc-isolation-transformer).

The problem is only reproduceable on a mobile version of the site. It is not reproduceable every time - the chance is something like 70%, so it sometimes takes a reload or three to repro it. The popup can appear anywhere on the page, so one might need to scroll the page to see it. The default browser on Android doesn't show the page source, so no idea what hypertext is served by the server and no idea if it's wrong hypertext being served or some problem when actually rendering the page in the browser.

My guess is that the mobile version of the site is tested a bit worse that the usual one and at some point incorrect hypertext is served. Just a guess though.

This problem is super annoying and looks like there is a more or less reliable repro. Could you please try addressing it?

Comment: I loaded that page 5 times in the default browser of Android 2.3.4. I got nothing.

Comment: Same results as @John using Dolphin (Andriod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the configuration file fails to load (usually due to slow connections -- MathJax will time out after 15 seconds wait), the configuration warning is displayed even though the page is properly configured (since the configuration didn't arrive in time, MathJax thinks the page isn't properly configured and gives the message).

Version 2.0 of MathJax is better about recognizing this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this on any mobile device, including my Nexus S (2.3.6).

It does *sound* like a networking issue, per [dpvc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161253/dpvc).

We are testing a new version of MathJax on our [mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/), to be deployed to the rest of the MathJax-enabled network once it's been sufficiently smoked out.  It's supposed to be [less susceptible to configuration loading issues](http://www.mathjax.org/2012/02/11/news/mathjax-v2-0-beta-now-available-on-cdn/).

Comment: Great! How will I know when new version is used everywhere?